# Does stax have a standard api such that I can swap out libraries to see what's fastest?

Tags: java, xml, stax

Does stax have a standard api such that I can somehow write my code in a generic way to read an xml file and load them into my java objects, and if I want I can swap out implementations of the xml stax parser?

What are the common stax parsers out there?

Answer (score 2):

yes, the `javax.xml.stream` classes are the standard StAX api in java.  the sun/oracle jdk comes with an older, slightly modified version of the woodstox StAX implementation.  for our purposes, we've included a newer version of the woodstox implementation and been very happy with it in terms of features and performance.  i have not done much research into other implementations, though.